# Looking for Script to change SMTP server address for office 2010

Tags: outlook, pop3

We have a pop3 email system. So we send our email out to a third party to do the scanning and filtering for us. We are switching companies to a new company at the end of the month. I need to change everyones SMTP server and remove the outgoing mail requires authentication in the more settings box.

We are running winxp, 7 32bit and 7 64bit, with office 2010. Does anyone know of a way to do this through a vb or any other script? Or am I just stuck manually changing all 100+ machines?

Thanks,

Comment: Are they on a domain?

Comment: Yes, all users are on the company domain

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest using a PRF file customized to what the settings should be and deploy that.  This way you can keep it for the future and edit it and redeploy if the need arises.  You can deploy it via GPO or script.

You can find more info on the PRF file and customizing Outlook here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062%28v=office.14%29.aspx

However, that said, I went and looked around and found this post on using Powershell with some code from Codeplex.  It's actually pretty cool, so I'm bookmarking it myself for future reference.  See here:  http://proproit.com/outlook/change-outlook-account-settings/

Comment: I am trying to get the prf to work. But for some reason I cant get it to just update only the SMTP section. If I dont add an account name in section 5, it creates a blank user. If I add %username%@domain.com, the prf when ran doesn't change anything. Is the %username@domain.com the correct way to specify whichever user is logged in at the time? Thanks again for the help guys

Comment: You are setting it to "modify" and not create, right?  It's been years since I've done a PRF, but I think it is just %username% without the domain.com part.  I think you also have to specify "overwriteexistingservice=yes".  You can also test deploy to a new Outlook and see if it takes properly, then test on existing accounts.